# AJAX call working from <body> but not from Javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

So the issue I'm currently having is that I'm trying to use an ajax call to send information to a php page to create an entry within a SQL database.

If I have the code within the  tag.  (So it's not within a function and it just calls on page load).

This is what is imported:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pos = "(44.18974214877667,-79.63154019848633)";
var place = "test";
var check = "on";
var priv = "yes";
$.ajax({ type:"POST",
         url:"backMap/locationCreation.php",
         data: { name: place, loc: pos, check: check, privacy: priv },
         success: function(data) { $("#awesomet").html(data);},
         error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError, data) {
                alert("Error: " + thrownError); }

});
</script>
```

When this is called upon page load it will run correctly and enter the information into the database.  The issue is that I would like this to happen when a button is called so the information could be entered by the user.

```
<button onClick="sendCreationRequest()" />Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">


function sendCreationRequest() {
   var place = $("#place").val();
   var pos = targetted.getPosition();
   var check = $("#checker").val();
   var priv = $("#privOp").val();
   $("#awesomet").html("GOT HERE.");

   $.ajax({ type:"POST",
         url:"backMap/locationCreation.php",
         data: { name: place, loc: pos, check: check, privacy: priv },
         success: function(data) { $("#awesomet").html(data);},
         error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError, data) {
        alert("Error: " + thrownError); }

   });
}
</script>
```

So the Awesomet div will be changed to "GOT HERE." when a button is pressed that should activate the function so it is entering the function.  I also had an alert going with all of the variables and they are correct.

When the button is clicked this is what comes up within the console:

```
CordovaLog - https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_ca/mapfiles/api-3/13/4/%7Bmain,visualization%7D.js: Line 12 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of undefined
Web Console - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of undefined:12.
```

I looked everywhere for some place that I was calling this but I couldn't find it.

I don't understand why it will work from a  on page load call, and why it won't work from a function call.

EDIT: Targetted is a Google Maps Marker.  When the call to get position is called.  It returns just fine.  I have put a alert(pos); within the code so when the button is pressed the alert does come up with the correct string.

EDIT: Okay, so I changed the:

```
var pos = targetted.getPosition();
```

to...

```
var pos = "(44.18974214877667,-79.63154019848633)";
```

The function call now works perfectly! However I don't understand why.  They are getting the same numbers within the variable.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the `code` that call the `sendCreationRequest()`? btw: any error on the console?

Comment: I posted how it's being called, just a regular button.  The onClick.  I don't think there are any console errors.  I am running this using Phonegap on an Android device.  It is pulling the pages from a server though so it shouldn't be an issue with Phonegap.

Comment: Try with `console.log()` for your `var`'s.

Comment: Okay, I'll update what the console says when the button is pressed on the original post.

Comment: in page load call you are using `var pos = "(44.18974214877667,-79.63154019848633)";` and inside function `var pos = targetted.getPosition();` so the error is in that `targetted.getPosition()`.

Comment: What's the targetted object? and does it have a method getPosition()?

Comment: Apologies, I'll add it in.  targetted is a marker from google maps.

Comment: Okay! So bystwn22 was right!  Good call! I changed the pos within the function call to the same as the one from the page load and it worked fine.  Any ideas why?

Comment: use `console.log( targetted, targetted.getPosition )` inside that function and tell what you got in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question.

Thanks to bystwn22 and Mansimran Singh.

It appeared the issue was with the targetted.getPosition();

targetted was a Marker from Google Maps.  It's getPosition() function returns something.  When printing it out using an alert() it appeared to be the same.

It turns out it wasn't actually a String but some sort of json statement.

The fix turned out to be:

```
var pos = ""+targetted.getPosition();
```

Simple but it works.

Thanks everyone for the input!